# How to pass category_id in the URL and make pagination work?

Tags: categories, pagination

In an efford to restrict page results to categories (that I pass in the URL from a link on another page) I came up with the following URL structure.

```
    my_site.com/index.php/template_group/category/category_url/
```

This tag code on the index page of this template_group:

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" limit="5" dynamic="off" category="{segment_2}" pagination="bottom" paginate_base="template_group/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/"}
```

*This works, but the pagination fails.*

I do get the correct pagination numbers at the end of my URL, but the tag does not listen anymore to the URL.

I tried very hard to get around this, but failed.

I do hope someone can shine a light here.
Many thanks.

Comment: Why {segment_2}? Isn't the category the {segment_3}?

Comment: Also even though {segment_3} is the category this still won't work because the channel:entries tag expects the category ID not short_name: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#category

Basically your thinking looks correct. After segment 2 & 3 EE doesn't care where the pagination segment is it will parse it (EE uses regex to find P0, P5, PX etc). Just beware of duplicated content, but a canonical url can get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing more work than you need to here. Are you familiar with the [Use Category URL Titles In Links? and Category URL Indicator preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html)?

These preferences will let you do exactly what you want, but dynamically (so, no need for `dynamic="off" category="{segment_2}"`).

Comment: Thank you, Derek, I have figured that out now using Category URL Titles In Links. (How can I set this question as solved?)

Comment: Glad to help - just click the checkmark icon next to my answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: done (I am new to this as you probably noticed :-)